# How do I prettily print out a git-diff output?

Tags: git, printing, diff, git-diff

for my upcoming Bachelor thesis, I am required to print out the git-diff output for the appendix of the paper. I really like the output of `git diff --color-words`, but I have absolutely no idea how to bring this - colored and with line numbers included - to a piece of paper on my Mac. I know there are tools like [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), but even with those I seem not able to make a pretty print out of the single file's diffs.

Well, I am pretty sure that I cannot be the only one with this problem, and I found some suggested ansi2html solutions, but they to not seem to work with my version of git (1.7.10.2). I also thought about simply printing the Github commit page (which is really pretty and kind of looks like what I need), but the browser will automatically remove all coloring and formatting when I am trying to print it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: diff the output into a file and print the file could be an option.

Comment: Yep, but then all the color is gone. :(

Comment: use http://www.quickdiff.com/ to diff and copy the output into TextEdit or any other html aware editor to print it. Sounds stupid but thats a simple way of doing it.

Comment: Well, the point is, I do not have a "before" and "after" / "left" and "right" file, but only a ready diff file. I also cannot just checkout the old and then the new version of the files, because we are talking about hundreds of files and thousands of lines changed..

Comment: this was actually a good question. Hope you still get some good answers with easy solutions.

Comment: @TimoJosten it's nice for others to put the solution you found in an answer, and accept it. Thanks!

Comment: The kernel-demystified.com link above is dead  8(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `aha`.  You can install it in ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install aha`.  Also see  https://github.com/theZiz/aha.

```
$ git diff --color-words | aha > index.html
$ firefox index.html
```

Firefox should then be able to print it in color.  Check out `aha --help` for some other cool options.

Comment: commenting to add: for people who want the normal diff output, just use --color instead of --color-words

Comment: Any solution for windows?

Answer (score 11):

I just tried an npm package hosted on Github: [pretty-diff](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/pretty-diff)

You install it via npm and run it as you would with `git-diff`, for example:

```
pretty-diff HEAD^
```

A new browser window opens and you can save it as html. I've tried to open it again in a different browser and colors are still showing. You can also use your github account to create gists and share them.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using a Mac with the terminal application, it is as simple as cut and pasting from the terminal to another application.

Answer (score 1):

What I found pretty useful is to just pipe it into [bat](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat), a modern cat.
If you want only a specific diff the command can be used as usual.

```
git diff | bat
```

You can also set up an alias in your shell profile to avoid typing it out every time.

Also [delta](https://github.com/dandavison/delta) is awesome.

Offical Description:
A syntax-highlighting pager for git, diff, and grep output

Even if you not set it as default pager in your configuration you can pipe the git diff output into it.

```bash
git diff origion/main | delta --side-by-side
```

is what I use daily