# Git diff that creates a local website

Tags: git, ssh, diff, git-diff

Is there a tool that will show me the output of git diff visually on a local website?

I only have ssh access to the remote server and I don't want to use ssh -X since its pretty clunky. So I would like to see it on a browser via http.

Comment: Why should the same information be better on a "web page" than in a terminal? A `diff` output is text, nothing that benefits much from being rendered inside an html client.

Comment: I've done this before using `aha` from [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643615/how-do-i-prettily-print-out-a-git-diff-output) - this will allow you to create an html file for your diff.

Comment: Alternatively clone the git repository and use any graphical git client you want locally. I mean `git` is a _decentralized_ source control utility

Comment: Which Server is Hosting your git repo? Microsoft Team Foundation Server for example allows you to see the diff in a web view.

Comment: The same info is better on a web page because I can scroll up and down easily with a mouse and the colors are better.
Aha seems a bit terminal like. Was looking for something that outputs the diff like it appears on github.
I am using github.

I don't want to commit it before i look at the diff.

Comment: You cannot see uncommitted diff on a server because servers show diff using objects database, and uncommitted diff is not there yet.

Comment: Try `git instaweb`.